# OCI Prefetch not working

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle-call-interface, prefetch, lob

We have an application that is using OCI, but we cannot seem to make prefetch working.

We have a select query on a table with a dozen of columns (amongst those is one CLOB column and one `MDSYS.GEOMETRY` column). The CLOB column is in 99% of the cases smaller than 4000 bytes and even in 50% of the cases empty.

Process is as follows:

- We set `OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS` to 500
- We bind the columns to output buffers, the CLOB is bind directly into a text buffer of 8000 bytes
- For the CLOB handle, we set `OCI_ATTR_LOBPREFETCH_SIZE` to 8000
- We use `OCISTMTEXECUTE` with iters 1 as one row is fetched into the buffer.

Now if we look with WireShark we see that the network packets are never filled (there is only one record per roundtrip).

If we execute the same select query with SQLDeveloper then the packets are nicely filled, so we can assume that row prefetching should work.

What are we missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Since I ran into the same problem recently:
`OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS` and `OCI_ATTR_LOBPREFETCH_SIZE` don't work together.

From [Oracle Docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci04sql.htm#i429698)

> Prefetching is not in effect if LONG, LOB or Opaque Type columns (such as XMLType) are part of the query.

Whenever you have LOBs in your result set, you can't use implicit prefetching via OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS and instead you need to use explicit row-fetching by calling OCIStmtFetch2() with a rowcount > 1. 
Then of course you need to setup buffers in advance, keep track of the already consumed rows and especially need to call OCIDefineArrayOfStruct() to inform oracle about your buffer layout.

Comment: If you want to check if everythin is working from inside the program - without asking wireshark, you can use oracle's internal statistics. Just query before you close your session: `select VALUE from V$SESSTAT natural join V$STATNAME where NAME = 'SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client' and SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')` which tells you how many rondtrips were made